# How do I attach a virus to any file for an antivirus project?

Tags: virus, anti-virus

I am making an Antivirus Project. It shall scan the files for any attached infection, but I don't know how does this work. So I firstly wanted to know, how does one attach any malicious executable file to any normal file to execute it on victim's PC?

Comment: I would expect that knowing the format of executable files would allow one to make modifications to it. Knowing how the machine code instructions stored in the executable work would be useful as well. Open the file, modify some bytes that leave the file as a valid executable with your bit of extra (or modified code), save the file, done.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to attach a virus to some other file you can download the [The EICAR Standard Anti-Virus Test File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EICAR_test_file) to test your antivirus software:

> The EICAR Standard Anti-Virus Test File or EICAR test file is a computer file that was developed by the European Institute for Computer Antivirus Research (EICAR) and Computer Antivirus Research Organization (CARO), to test the response of computer antivirus (AV) programs. **Instead of using real malware, which could do real damage, this test file allows people to test anti-virus software without having to use a real computer virus.**

See [Intended use](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html) for more information:

**The Anti-Malware Testfile**

> This test file has been provided to EICAR for distribution as the "EICAR Standard Anti-Virus Test File", and it satisfies all the criteria listed above. It is safe to pass around, because it is not a virus, and does not include any fragments of viral code. Most products react to it as if it were a virus (though they typically report it with an obvious name, such as "EICAR-AV-Test").
>
> The file is a legitimate DOS program, and produces sensible results when run (it prints the message "EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!").
>
> It is also short and simple - in fact, it consists entirely of printable ASCII characters, so that it can easily be created with a regular text editor. Any anti-virus product that supports the EICAR test file should detect it in any file providing that the file starts with the following 68 characters, and is exactly 68 bytes long:

```
X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*
```

> The first 68 characters is the known string. It may be optionally appended by any combination of whitespace characters with the total file length not exceeding 128 characters. The only whitespace characters allowed are the space character, tab, LF, CR, CTRL-Z. To keep things simple the file uses only upper case letters, digits and punctuation marks, and does not include spaces. The only thing to watch out for when typing in the test file is that the third character is the capital letter "O", not the digit zero.
>
> You are encouraged to make use of the EICAR test file. **If you are aware of people who are looking for real viruses "for test purposes", bring the test file to their attention.** If you are aware of people who are discussing the possibility of an industry-standard test file, tell them about www.eicar.org, and point them at this article.

The test file can be download from (http://www.eicar.org/85-0-Download.html) in various different formats:

> In order to facilitate various scenarios, we provide 4 files for download. The first, eicar.com, contains the ASCII string as described above. The second file, eicar.com.txt, is a copy of this file with a different filename. Some readers reported problems when downloading the first file, which can be circumvented when using the second version. Just download and rename the file to "eicar.com". That will do the trick. The third version contains the test file inside a zip ARCHIVEe. A good anti-virus scanner will spot a 'virus' inside an ARCHIVEe. The last version is a zip ARCHIVEes containing the third file. This file can be used to see whether the virus scanner checks ARCHIVEes more than only one level deep.

Comment: Standalone virus files can be easily detected by having its signatures. The problem comes when these malicious codes are binded/attached to some host file. So I want to know, how to bind these files with any .exe file.

Comment: You're asking for advice in a public forum about how to spread malware.  Assuming you have good intentions, aren't you worried about degenerates who might read the answers?

Comment: A security consultant gets to know about a loophole when he has a source code which has been compromised!
In the same way I wish to know the actual binding process which can give me an idea to catch hold off such malicious files.

Always **Good** precedes **bad**

Answer (score 2):

The following string is the EICAR test virus.  It is non-malicious code that will be detected by any AV scanning software out there for the purposes of testing.

If your AV is configured correctly, placing the following string into the body of an e-mail should trigger an A/V alert.

`X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*`

Alternatively, you could save it to a file using any extension you like and and it should produce the same effect as well.

Also, appending it to the end of an existing file should also trigger an AV alert.

You can find more information about it [here](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html).

Comment: EICAR is not detected by all AV programs.  Most of the major ones do, but sometimes you will find one that does not detect it.

Comment: I would like to know which ones don't because the whole point of that test virus is to determine whether or not your AV software is working properly.  I would tend to avoid buying a product for which I have no way of knowing if it actually works.

Comment: Yea, the EICAR test is just to verify if your AV is in a working condition or not.

Comment: @WesSayeed Hard to say.  I came across a AV program a while back that did not support it.  There is no definitive list, other than it is recognized by most "major" AV programs.